# Vector of your of type in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I've searched for a lot of topics on StackOverflow and Google, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
template<class T>
class E {
    T data;
};
int main() {
    vector<E> vector1;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns build error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'
     vector<E> vector1;
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the template parameter of `E`.

Comment: Thanks! I spent lot of time to repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

```
int main() {
    vector<E<int>> vector1;
    return 0;
}
```